# Port .NET Framework library to .NET Core with auto-generated code

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a .NET Framework [library](https://github.com/josephrodriguez/Skyland.Pipeline) which I want to be supported in .NET Core for later deployment in [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org) with `AppVeyor`. After use this excellent tool [.Net Portability Analyzer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b) which determines the percentage of the code of your project what is portable to .NET Core and conflicts to support each of the selected platforms.

The only detected problem is the use of Reflection on `Resource.Designer.cs` file which is known to be not supported in .NET Core in the traditional way.

On `Resources.Designer.cs` file exist the following auto-generated code:

```
internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {
    get {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(resourceMan, null)) {
            global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Skyland.Pipeline.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
            resourceMan = temp;
        }
        return resourceMan;
    }
}
```

The problem here is the use of `typeof(Resources).Assembly` and this can be replaced by `typeof(Resource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly` but as warn the comment on this file:

> Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if the code is regenerated.

I don´t want abandon the `.csproj` schema overall after this [announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/) of Microsoft and migrate my project to a .Net Core library with `.xproj / .project.json` project schema with which I solve my problem.

Also do not think there is an *magic* alternative using conditional compilation to solve this problem.

**Questions:**

- There is any way to solve this problem maintaining the `.csproj` schema and creating a `.project.json` file?

Comment: Well for the warning that changes might be lost, you can test it to see if it is actually the case... For example, for Windows Forms designer file, the destructor is not usually modified once you have some controls. Obviously, there is no guarantee that it will still works forever but I doubt that any changes would be made for these old technologies...